# How to inherit from ForeignKey to extend model field?

Tags: python, django, model, overriding, field

I am trying to create a custom ForeignKey. I have inherited from it and trying to override `__init__` method to provide the positional arguments `to` and `on_delete` like the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CurrentUserField(models.ForeignKey):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(User, models.CASCADE, **kwargs)


class DemoModel(models.Model):
    owner = CurrentUserField()
    info = models.TextField()
```

It gives me the following error when I am running `makemigrations`:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'on_delete'
```

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. I am only providing two values for two positional arguments.

Comment: Which version of Django you are using?

Comment: I am using Django 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose if you pass `User` and `on delete` parameters in your owner field itself you could see how Django is converting its arguments.

EXAMPLE

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class CurrentUserField(models.ForeignKey):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for i in args:
            print(i, "This is an argument")

        for j in kwargs.items():
            print(j, "This is a keyword argument")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class DemoModel(models.Model):
    owner = CurrentUserField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    info = models.TextField()
```

OUTPUT

```
<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'> This is an argument
('on_delete', <function CASCADE at 0x103900400>) This is a keyword argument
('on_delete', <function CASCADE at 0x103900400>) This is a keyword argument
('to', 'auth.User') This is a keyword argument
('on_delete', <function CASCADE at 0x103900400>) This is a keyword argument
('to', 'auth.User') This is a keyword argument
```

as you can see Django is converting `auth.User` and `models.CASCADE` into a dictionary with keys `to` and `on_delete` respectively. i.e., `{'to': 'auth.User', 'on_delete': <function CASCADE at 0x103900400>}`.

So in your case you should set the default value for the keys `to` and `on_delete` to get the expected behaviour.

i.e.,

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class CurrentUserField(models.ForeignKey):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('to', User)
        kwargs.setdefault('on_delete', models.CASCADE)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class DemoModel(models.Model):
    owner = CurrentUserField()
    info = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Is there any other way I can set the default values for the arguments? Or do I always have to use `setdefault` ?

Comment: I thing `kwargs.setdefault` could be the better option here.